# Editing Recurring Contributions without user login

Tags: civicontribute, email, message-templates, recurring-contributions

How do I generate an e-mail with a link to get to the dashboard so the user can edit the credit card details of a recurring contribution, without the user having to have login privileges to get to that dashboard?

Credit cards are expiring or card numbers change, and we need a way for the user to update their cards.  Preferably without going through a whole new creation process. The dashboard is there, but they can't access it without having far too much power given to them through the ACL's.

CiviCRM 4.7, Wordpress, Authorize.net

Comment: Originally titled: Resending Recurring Contributions E-mail, with a question of: 

I must not be searching the right keywords, because I'm almost positive I read the answer to this question in the docs. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find it again.

How do I resend the e-mail for recurring contributions that gives the contributor the links for editing or canceling their contributions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I almost have this polished, just one little piece that may be beyond what my pea brain can handle. The short of it is that from the affected contact you need to send an e-mail with tokens. (I've put this into a template.) In the body of the e-mail put a link similar to this:

https://yoursite.com/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/updatebilling&reset=1&crid=XX&{contact.checksum}&cid={contact.contact_id}&context=dashboard

You need to replace the crid=XX with the correct crid for that failed transaction.  The only way I've found to get that crid from the front end is through a few steps.
1.  Open up the contact of the failed contribution.
2.  Click on the "Actions" button, then Right Click on the "Contact Dashboard" and choose "Open in new Tab."  This will open up the dashboard in a separate tab, as you'll need the first page later and can't easily get back to it.
3.  On the Contact Dashboard page, you'll find a "Recurring Contributions" line.  Click the "more" button, then Right Click on the "Change Billing Details" and choose "Open in new Tab."  This will open up the "Billing Details" in a new tab.  In the address bar, you'll find the "crid=" value buried in the string.

Moving forward, I'm hoping that someone with more skills than I can figure out how to add this crid as a token, and then be able to search for failed contributions and send the template e-mail to multiple contacts at once.  To go even a step further, being able to automate this once a failed transaction happens, the system automatically sends out this notice.

Comment: Oh, and instead of just a search, how about running the template e-mail out from the results of a report?

Comment: did this ever get progressed - it looks like a lonely post at this point but with some interesting possibilities

Comment: also can you clarify what is the issue of letting a contact access their own dashboard to do this updating (which was news to me that it could be done so thx for pointing that out)

Comment: in case it is helpful to others, you can see the crid bby hovering on the relevant Recurring Contribution in the lower section of their Contribution Tab too ie, click on more, right click and 'copy url' for the change billing details, then just add on the checksum token and swop the cid with the contact.id token

Comment: I had problems with the above link

Comment: need to change an & to a ? eg civicrm/contribute/updatebilling?reset=1&crid=XX&{contact.checksum}&cid={contact.contact_id}

Comment: and konadave has pointed out the contact id is not a required token for this - https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/gpmf3d3pmi8ozm1tgdu7jnb1ba

Comment: RE: Customers accessing their own dashboard.  It was a permissions issue.  If I gave them access to the control panel, they could jump to other contacts.  They weren't limited to only their records.  It wasn't obvious to the user, but simply changing the record ID in the URL allowed them to successfully transverse records.  Here's the discussion on permissions:  http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/10124/update-credit-card-info-permissions

Answer (score 2):

adding as a new answer. the link that would need to be sent out would look like

civicrm/contribute/updatebilling?reset=1&crid=XX&{contact.ch‌​ecksum}

since the contact id token is not checked during this process and hence not required.

Comment: Great work Pete.  Glad to know that it's helping somebody else.  We've been successfully sending out the original link for a while now.  Are you perhaps using Drupal instead of WordPress?  Or perhaps something has been added since I originally put it together.  Either way, it's a significant improvement.  I'll attempt to verify it via WordPress.

Comment: yep my urls are def. drupal ones.

Comment: and we are hoping to scope what it would take to add a link under 'more' so that we can 'send email' which would pop up the email box with the link with correct crid inserted

Comment: Ohhhh!  Pretty!  Shiny!  Me likes it!  (If you aren't a Gollum fan, well, can I pray for you? ;-) )  That would be a great time saver.  Auto-filling the template and automating will take it from a five minute process to 30 seconds!

Comment: it looks like it could be a simple job to do this but haven't got any response from the client that was initially interested in this. get in touch via fuzion.co.nz if you might be able to help push this along

Comment: anyone thought about this since 2016? :)

Comment: me. again. now.

Comment: Thanks Petednz, we basically took this option off our site due to it not working so always happy to revisit.

Comment: @petednz-fuzion any updates? We went with this https://civicrm.org/blog/matt-dunne/losing-monthly-donations-because-out-date-credit-card-information and it seems to be working

Comment: i don't recall us taking this any further