# How can I increase the amount an existing monthly sustainer is giving?

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, authorize.net

We're on CiviCRM 4.6.19, Drupal 7.50 and we use Authorize.net for payment processing.

If I simply want to increase the amount an existing monthly sustainer is giving, should I be able to do that by changing the monthly "subscription" amount in Authorize before the next monthly transaction?

Is there a recommended way to do this in CiviCRM itself?

Answer (score 5):

This won't work, because CiviCRM doesn't communicate with Authorize.Net regarding changes to recurring billing.  Only token-based payment processors (e.g. iATS) do.

While I can't answer specifically for Authorize.Net, in PayPal you can change the billing amount by no more than 20% every 6 months without entering new card info.  You do this from the PayPal UI.

Comment: Jon, thanks, Authorize doesn't communicate either way for a change in amount - to or from Civi? So only way to do an increase is to start a new monthly sustaining contribution/membership?

Comment: Here's a link to my blog post about how iATS (token-based) payment processors differ from the Auth.net/paypal version: https://civicrm.org/blog/alan-dixon/recurring-payments-advanced-functions Note that iATS is not the only token-based payment processor for CiviCRM, but iATS is the only one that's funded development of it's plugin (and development of CiviCRM in general).

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to cancel the transaction via Authorize.net's merchant portal, cancel the recurring contribution in civi, and create a new recurring gift.

Civi can't do it all internally.

Answer (score 0):

Would this process not work?  If not, please comment and give some feedback so that I can alter what I'm expecting.

[Editing Recurring Contributions without user login](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/11339/resending-recurring-contributions-e-mail/14538#14538)