# How can I update a credit/debit card number, card billing address, or card expiration date to continue transaction processing - on Authorize.net

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, authorize.net

We're on CiviCRM 4.6.19, Drupal 7.50 and using Authorize.net for payment processing.

When a credit/debit card number, card billing address, or card expiration date has changed, should simply updating the subscription with the new card info in Authorize for an ongoing monthly sustainer continue the processing uninterrupted, on the same date?

UPDATE for clarification - The monthly/recurring *amount* will remain the same. The goal is to resume the same monthly/recurring contribution in the same amount by fixing an error with processing by updating the "subscription" in Authorize with the new card number, billing address and/or expiration date.

Answer (score 1):

Automatic recurring billing is an extra feature in Authnet (ARB) that you usually have to request. In order for Authnet to communicate to the CiviCRM that a recurring transaction has taken place, you must install a **silent post URL** in the designated field within the Authnet portal, under **Account > Settings > Silent Post URL**.

The silent post URL for a Drupal site is: `https://yoursite.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/authorizeIPN.php`

Once that's established, the credit card and billing information would need to be managed through the Authnet portal since CiviCRM does not store credit card numbers. If you update the information proactively, it should update everything else in the CRM automatically.

https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Authorize.net+Configuration

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you update the subscription it will update the amount that you have updated but it wont interrupt the processing or date of transaction unless you edit that date.

Comment: Gary, thanks, but the question is not about the amount - the amount will remain the same. It's about the card number, card billing address and/or card expiration date. See my update above. I asked a separate question about changing the amount at http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/14382/how-can-i-increase-the-amount-an-existing-monthly-sustainer-is-giving and

Comment: We've had some experience of this with Auth.net. The Civi screens that enable users or admin team to update CC details work well, exactly as you are hoping above - if you are in $USD. If you are in £GBP like us, there is a bug in Auth.net that defaults the currency to $USD if you make any change to the credit card info, thereby making future transactions fail if the currency is expected in £GBP. I've been trying to get them to fix this bug (they have admitted it exists to us) for 2.5 years now! If anyone knows of any other info on this we'd be very delighted to know.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you are looking for is answered here:

[Editing Recurring Contributions without user login](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/11339/editing-recurring-contributions-without-user-login)

However, to re-process the current month, I'm asking that question over here:

[How to re-process failed recurring contributions after updating card info?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/14844/how-to-re-process-failed-recurring-contributions-after-updating-card-info)

Comment: G H thanks but my question is not about sending contributions e-mails.

Comment: Sorry Joe, I think I need to go relabel that question, as the answer is a bit different that than the question.  The answer actually sends an e-mail to the user to giving them a dashboard to update their credit card info.

Answer (score 0):

Added authorize.net to your Title; with the iATS Extension you manage your contacts and their recurring series from within CiviCRM so you can eg change someone's credit card number associated with a series - from within CiviCRM (and thus not interrupting and processing);