# Self-service update of credit card details - how to notify staff to re-process recurring contribution?

Tags: civicontribute, recurring-contributions, iats

We would like to send out links for credit card recurring donors to update their credit card when a donation fails, using the [solution from this question.](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/11339/editing-recurring-contributions-without-user-login) Then, we need to somehow notify staff that the donor has made the update, so we can re-process their recurring donation to cover the missed donation. Does someone have a solution for this notification?

There is a notification sent to the donor about the update, but that only goes to the donor. I've tried CiviRules on recurring donation change, but that does not appear to be triggered by updating credit card details through this link.

We're using IATS.

Comment: Or even: is there any way to find out a credit card has been updated at all other than comparing the credit card number or waiting until it processes again? Is there any way to check this manually?

Comment: we have an extension that sends nominated admins an email when a CC payment fails. would that be any help?

Comment: @petednz-fuzion Actually, it would! Not really for this issue, but it would be helpful otherwise. Can you share?

Comment: ok. have a blog started about it so shall get that finished and hopefully paste link back here

Comment: Hey Lars - you can also configure Email when payment fails in the iATS Extension Settings screen

Comment: @KarinG-SemperIT I had forgotten about that, because it doesn't seem to be working for us. Could you have look? Or any suggestions about why that might be?

Answer (score 3):

This works in core! There is an activity created of type Update Recurring Contribution Billing Details when a contact updates their details through the form. And then you can add a CiviRule to send an email when this activity is created. That will also capture back office updates and ideally it wouldn't but this is bearable. A back office update will have a target contact while a self service one will not, but I don't think there is any way to add lack of target contact as a condition in Civirules.

What I did is to only trigger on source contact activities and exclude updates with the source contact ID of one of our staff who might update a credit card from the CiviRule. Not pretty, but good enough.

[image]

Not sure if this always worked and somehow my testing didn't work before or something was fixed in our latest update to 5.35.1.

Answer (score 0):

> as we discussed over email please log an issue for this in our iATS Extension Github account re: logging an activity when a user updates their credit card.

Comment: https://github.com/iATSPayments/com.iatspayments.civicrm/issues/345